# Rails - MissingTemplate occurred in controller#action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, googlebot

I have following scheme:

click on this link

```
= link_to 'Ping', {:controller => 'articles', :action => 'info_form', :to_article => @article.id}
```

go to ArticlesController

```
  def info_form
    @info = current_user unless current_user.nil?
    @to_article_id = Article.find(params[:to_article])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.js 
     end
  end
```

then is called `articles/info_form.js.haml`

```
$('#article_form').html("#{escape_javascript(render('info'))}");
$('#article_form_window').modal('toggle');
```

and `_info.html.haml`

```
here is a form
```

This is the flow of actions in my app and it's working great.
But in the production, several times a day I am getting this error messages:

```
A ActionView::MissingTemplate occurred in articles#info_form: 

Missing template articles/info_form, application/info_form with
```

In the log is following:

```
Request: 
* URL : http://web.com/articles/info_form?to_article=37
* HTTP_FROM : googlebot(at)googlebot.com
* HTTP_USER_AGENT : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

The URL which gives this errors is the URL, which is visited by google bot. How can I fix this error? Because, the problematic URL is not clickable for the "usual" users, giving the error just that time, when Google bot visit it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have HTML view of that action?

`info_form.html.haml`

Comment: No, I don't. I implemented the functionality without this file, why I need this file?

Comment: It is default template for HTML request. There should be information accessible by normal URI request. As you see you have format.html, Google want to html format, you don't have view for it. So you get error missing template. Your link is public accessible. If you want ajax request add to ``link_to`` this: ``data: { remote: true }``